# Show object where date > current date

Tags: javascript, css, mongodb, mongoose

How do I get my page to only show my 'events' where the event_date is in the future?

```
<% for (let event of events){%>
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><%= event.event_name %> </h5>
                    <p class="text">Artist: <%= event.artist.username %></p>
                    <p class="text"><%= event.location %> </p>
                    <p class="text">
                        <small class="text-muted"><%= event.description %> </small>
                    </p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/events/<%= event.id %>">View Event</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }%>
```

Right now this index page works great but I'd love for it to be like:

```
<% for (let event of events where event_date > datetime-local){%>
```

Obviously this is not sql and above won't work. How do I get my index page to only show future-dated events?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to compare dates in js, use the built-in [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and compare them using `Date.getTime()`. You can get the current date by calling the constructor `new Date()` without passing it a value:

```js
let date1_timestamp = 1231069762975;
let date1 = new Date(date1_timestamp /* timestamp */);
let date2 = new Date(); // current date

console.log(date1.getTime() < date2.getTime());

// or, if you already have the timestamp
console.log(date1_timestamp < date2.getTime());
```

Also, something to keep in mind about `Date` in case you're working with UNIX timestamps: the timestamp used by `Date` it is *not* the same as the UNIX timestamp. The UNIX timestamp is in *seconds*, whereas the js timestamp is in *milliseconds*.

Comment: Hi @Ætérnal - thanks for the response but I'm looking to filter *out* events from my database where the date is in the past. I've already applied a date attribute to the "event" under "event_date" and would like to use that field to filter out past events from my index page.